# Login via SSO (SAML) for ANY user from the Internet (not just a corporate one)

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, openid, saml, okta

I have included SSO (SAML) authorization in my existing application. But for me it was an unpleasant surprise to find that only 2 types of users can use the login through the providers I added (Okta, Azure AD):

- Users who are located in the corporate directory of the provider (for example, I made an application on my account, there are no more
  users. This means that any other user will not be able to use the
  login form, because he is not a member of my tenant)
- Third-party users of companies, whose administrators have added a
  template of my application from the general list and connected their
  users to it.

I expected other results, I need **ANY user** to be able to log in through these providers (regardless of whether he is in the corporate directory or has his own separate account that is not integrated into my application)
I thought about changing the SAML protocol to OIDC (OpenID Connect), but it seems to me that everything will work in the same way (at least Azure AD, because it seems there are no other options for working with it, except for corporate distribution)

Who had a similar experience, could you tell me what I should use among technologies and protocols so that **ABSOLUTELY ANY user can log into my application** through Okta / Azure AD / Google? Thanks!

[Azure AD login fail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoNnZ.jpg)

[Okta login fail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE3V3.png)

Comment: If you don't know where the target users are located, you need to offer a choice, like 'SSO with Okta', 'SSO with Azure AD' ...

Comment: SAML and OIDC both require an "identity provider", someone that can authenticate the user. In addition, they both require you as a service provider validate those users with a trust mechanism that YOU as the service provider have to configure between you and the identity provider. As such, I don't think that either of these mechanisms are what you are looking for... The closest you'll get is login with Facebook/Google via OIDC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure AD OAuth2 flows and multitenant apps with MSA (personal account) support to allow any user from any domains and personal accounts to login into your application. Or you can switch to Azure AD B2C (which also relies on OAuth2) to connect different identity providers (Local Azure B2C, Azure AD, Facebook, Google, Amazon, Github, Linked in, Twitter, generics, etc) and allow all their users to login into your application.